# How can I restart iptables in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: iptables, firewall, docker

To manage my firewall I use ufw. But Docker modifies itpables rules directly. I'm trying to do some testing to see what the effect of setting `"iptables": false` in /etc/docker/daemon.json, but it seems that once Docker has been started the iptables rules get set and won't go away:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "iptables": false
}

$ sudo systemctl stop containerd docker.service docker.socket

$ sudo iptables -L | grep -i docker
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
```

I figured out pretty quickly that there's no systemd unit for iptables, so I tried restarting ufw several different ways, but I guess since Docker bypasses ufw it doesn't have any effect.

I'm guessing rebooting my computer would do the trick but that's what I'm trying to avoid since I would like to do some testing that involves enabling and disabling the Docker iptables integration several times and I don't want to reboot every time.

Comment: Would [iptables-apply](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/iptables-apply.8.html) give you what you need? This allows you to make changes with an option to have the new rule(s) reverted after X seconds in the event there’s an issue that messes up your networking 